# How to model and estimate interference and subsequent shocks on panel data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, panel-data

I have the following setting:

In my factory, we have mutliple assembly lines(>10). Each line produces an amout of itmes every day, with some weekly and mothly production peeks.

Thus its basically a panel of multiples lines producing some output over some period of time. Sometimes, the line is being stopped due to technical reasons and the productions stopps on that line immediately as well. That may affect running lines indirectly, since they may compensate for the stopped one.
That stoppage may last for several days or is solved on the same day.

The question is how can I estimate the impact of line stoppings - What is here the best way to go?

-----> Do stoped lines lead to an increase in production on the running lines?

-----> Is there anyway to quantify the overall shift/spill with corresponding uncertainty like - "If a line stops then the overall production of items decreases/increases by some amount within some confidence interval"?

```
# Example data where machine_stops correspond to either True or False

# Line1
dates_machine_works = seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'),as.Date('2017-12-31'), by ="day")

machine_output <- ts(rpois(length(dates_machine_works), lambda = 100),     # random data
                     start = c(2016, as.numeric(format(dates_machine_works[1], "%j"))),
                     frequency = 365)

machine_stops <- rbinom(n=length(dates_machine_works), size=1, prob=0.01)           
line_name = rep("machine_line1", length(dates_machine_works))
output_machine_line1 <- cbind.data.frame(dates_machine_works, machine_stops, machine_output,line_name)



# Line2
dates_machine_works = seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'),as.Date('2017-12-31'), by ="day")

machine_output <- ts(rpois(length(dates_machine_works), lambda = 100),     # random data
                     start = c(2016, as.numeric(format(dates_machine_works[1], "%j"))),
                     frequency = 365)

machine_stops <- rbinom(n=length(dates_machine_works), size=1, prob=0.01)           
line_name = rep("machine_line2", length(dates_machine_works))
output_machine_line2 <- cbind.data.frame(dates_machine_works, machine_stops, machine_output,line_name)


# Line3
dates_machine_works = seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'),as.Date('2017-12-31'), by ="day")

machine_output <- ts(rpois(length(dates_machine_works), lambda = 100),     # random data
                     start = c(2016, as.numeric(format(dates_machine_works[1], "%j"))),
                     frequency = 365)

machine_stops <- rbinom(n=length(dates_machine_works), size=1, prob=0.01)           
line_name = rep("machine_line3", length(dates_machine_works))
output_machine_line3 <- cbind.data.frame(dates_machine_works, machine_stops, machine_output,line_name)
```

The data looks like this.

```
R> head(output_machine_line3)
  dates_machine_works machine_stops machine_output     line_name
1          2016-01-01             0             92 machine_line3
2          2016-01-02             0             78 machine_line3
3          2016-01-03             0            128 machine_line3
4          2016-01-04             0             95 machine_line3
5          2016-01-05             0            119 machine_line3
6          2016-01-06             0             90 machine_line3

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# First approach using vars
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
library(xts)
library(vars)

line1 <- ts(output_machine_line1$machine_output, start=c(2016, 1), end=c(2017, 12), frequency=365)
line2 <- ts(output_machine_line2$machine_output, start=c(2016, 1), end=c(2017, 12), frequency=365)
line3 <- ts(output_machine_line3$machine_output, start=c(2016, 1), end=c(2017, 12), frequency=365)

rates.ts = cbind(line1,line2,line3) 

plot(rates.ts)
drates.ts <- diff(rates.ts)
plot(drates.ts)

VARselect(drates.ts, lag.max = 8, type = "const")


mod1 <- VAR(drates.ts, p = 5, type = "const")

irf1 <- irf(mod1, impulse = "line1", response = c("line1","line2", "line3"), ortho = TRUE, n.ahead = 6)

plot(irf1)
```

Generally, Im not sure whether it is the right directions since Im somehow not using the panel nature at all. Additionally, the impulse is changing between the time series and has a reciprocal nature.
Appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that line stoppages are *arguably random accidents*, you have a great pseudo-experiment. You can check if the production of the surviving lines is significantly better on days when a line is down. A mean comparison test of the production of "surviving lines" is a pretty good test.   Unless the line stoppages are planned, this is a pretty good approach.

You could even run a simple regression (it looks like you're using Poisson which is great):

```
  Production in each surviving line ~ number of downed lines
```

And if you find a positive and significant coefficient, you've got a decent argument.

Don't do more work than you have to.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. May I ask you to clarify the last suggestion. Are you expecting some correlation between the number of downed lines and the "overall" Production aka `the overall sum of output ~ number of downed lines`  where the increase of the downed lines may cause an decrease in overall production or are you suggesting to run individual models for each line (which I would not fully understand)

Comment: One model using the out put of each line (not summed, not overall production). Example: If you have 5 lines and one is down, you have 4 data points, 4 production observations, each having 1 downed line.

Comment: I'll note that their might be some gains using panel data setups, though. However, if we (further) assume each of the lines are identical in nature, then you're probably fine.